# Definition 10.3 from PMA Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

It's an excerpt from Rudin's book. I can't understand the following moments:

1) Why he considers  continuous function with compact support? Why compactness is so important?

2) Why equation (3) has the meaning? Why $f$ is zero on the complement of $I^k$?

3) Why integral in (3) is independent of the choice $I^k$? It's not obvious to me.

Can anyone give an answer to my above questions? I would be very grateful.

Comment: I just remember one line he said in the beginning of this chapter: "the proper setting for the discussion should be the Lebesgue integral." Seeing this I simply skipped this chapter and embarked upon his *Real and Complex Analysis*. :)

Comment: @Vim: One still needs to learn multivariable analysis. I wouldn't choose Rudin's text for that material, but, nevertheless ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the answer to 1) is that the Riemann integral is defined only on rectangles, so you need to be able to enclose the set of points $x$ where $f(x)\ne 0$ in a giant rectangle and then integrate over that rectangle. That's what he's doing with the integral over the $k$-cell $I^k$. I'm not sure what you mean by 2); the answer to 2) should be the answer to 3). Consider any two rectangles (or $k$-cells) containing the support of $f$. On any subrectangle contained in one of those rectangles but not in the other, we have $f=0$, so integrating $f$ over that subrectangle will give $0$.

Comment: 1) If $\text{supp}(f)$ is compact then it's closed + bounded. Hence support of $f$ is contained in some $k$-cell. Right?

Comment: Yes, sure. I guess I took that for granted. :)

Comment: 2) Rudin defines equation (3). So $f$ must be zero on complement of $I^k$. If I am right how to prove it?

Comment: That's the point of our choice of $k$-cell. All the points where $f(x)\ne 0$ are contained in the interior of the $k$-cell. Thus, outside the $k$-cell, $f$ is $0$ everywhere!

Comment: Sorry that I am asking a lot of questions but If $\text{supp}(f)\subset I^k$ then also $\{x:f(x)\neq 0\}\subset I^k$ . Hence $f\equiv 0$ out the $I^k$. Right?

Comment: I think that's precisely what I just said :) Yes.

Comment: I guess that this is the last question :) Why in definition of support we consider the closure of $\{x:f(x)\neq 0\}$ but not $\{x:f(x)\neq 0\}$?

Comment: So that you can have a compact set to work with. Saying compact support is (in Euclidean space) equivalent to saying bounded support.  Although you will eventually learn measure theory and Lebesgue integration, for purposes of the Riemann integral we want to integrate over compact objects.

Comment: About the last remark: If $I^k$ and $J^k$ be two $k$-cells. We must prove that $\int \limits_{I^k}f=\int \limits_{J^k}f$.

As you say let $Q^k\subset I^k$ but $Q^k\nsubseteq J^k$. How to conclude that $\int \limits_{I^k}f=\int \limits_{J^k}f$?

Comment: Draw pictures and think about it.

Comment: I prove it but quite different than you recommended. Let $I^k$ and $J^k$ be two $k$-cells containing $\text{supp}(f)$. Then $P^k=I^k\cap J^k$ also contains $\text{supp}(f)$. Then $\int \limits_{I^k}=\int \limits_{P^k}+\int \limits_{I^k\setminus P^k}=\int \limits_{P^k}=\int \limits_{J^k}$ 

Right?

Comment: That is essentially what I had in mind. But to do $I^k\backslash P^k$, you have to split it up into a union of $k$-cells, officially.

Comment: Yes. But union of $k$-cells is smth difficult? I don't understand your remark

Comment: The only thing you have defined so far is the integral over a $k$-cell. So if you have something complicated, you have to break it up into $k$-cells and use additivity.

Comment: How to prove that additivity is also true for such type of integrals?